# Workbook with Pivot Tables Opens Very Slowly

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

I am working with an Excel 2013 workbook on Windows 10.  It has ten pivot tables and takes a long time (~2 mins) to open.  I have tried a lot of things to speed this up to no avail.  Here are the specs:

The workbook is about 40 Mbytes in size.  It is an *.xlsm file with a significant VBA app that can be activated by clicking a button.  However, there is no Workbook Open event and no worksheet level events.

All of the pivot tables are based on data from a single worksheet within the workbook. No external data.

All of the pivot tables are set to NOT refresh on open.  They are also set to not save data.  (I tried both ways and if anything setting it to save data caused it to take longer to open.)

The pivot tables contain no formulas.  The data worksheet has no formulas.  The workbook in its entirety has very few formulas.  The app creates formulas to populate the sheets, but then converts all of the formulas to values.

The pivot tables did have conditional formats, but even after deleting them all, the workbook still takes about the same time to come up.

This is not the startup delay issue.  There is a dialog telling me that the load is 0% … 20% … 40% … complete.

I deleted just the pivot table sheets from the workbook and the workbook comes up in just a few seconds.

I also created a new workbook by copying over all the sheets and code thinking there might be a low-level corruption issue, but the copy didn't come up any faster.

Do pivot tables just naturally come up slow?  Is there any property or setting I can change to speed up the workbook opening process?  A number of people use these workbooks and are very dissatisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click inside pivot, Pivot Table options, Data tab, clear/uncheck the checkbox "Save source data with file."

Every time you create a Pivot, Excel stores a copy of the source data in the file and uses it to run queries. If you created 10 Pivots separately, you'll have 10 caches saved in the file making it bloated/slow. To optimize the file, you'll want to create a Pivot and then COPY that Pivot for ALL other Pivots that use the SAME data table. This will ensure you use only 1 cache instead of 10. Also, as a bonus, when you refresh one it'll refresh all of them.

**Only keep this unchecked if there's no external data.

Cheers

Comment: I had experimented with the 'Save source data with file'.  Initially all of the pivot tables had this box unchecked.  I thought that by checking it, that it would save the data and thus would not need to repopulate the pivot tables on open, but as you say when I checked the box the performance was worse.

Comment: I'll look into the shared cache idea.  The data table is huge and each pivot table only uses a slice of it, but if I have them all look at the same larger cache and just show the different subsets in the different tables then that might do the trick.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah that's really the only thing I think it could be, especially with a large data set. If it is possible to use the same data range for each pivot, I'd try that route. Another option would be to use Power Pivot/Power Query which compresses the data really well.

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/xlPivot11.html this is a good resource to deal with pivot cache. best of luck